How to write back in a memory mapped file with MAP_PRIVATE?
When memory mapping a file with the MAP_PRIVATE flag, the modifications (writes) only exist in memory and are not written back to the file.
According to the man pages, calling msync (3) on a such a mapping does NOT writes the changes back: "When the msync() function is called on MAP_PRIVATE mappings, any modified data shall not be written to the underlying object and shall not cause such data to be made visible to other processes"
https://linux.die.net/man/3/msync So: is there a way to write the changes back to the file?
An obvious application is:

mapping the file with MAP_PRIVATE
make some modifications in memory only (fast) while keeping the original version on disk (safe)
at some point (when the user decides, and/or once the consistency of the changes have been verified) writing the modifications to the disk

At the moment what I'm doing is something like:
    int fd = open("aaa",O_RDWR);
    void* p = mmap ( NULL
                   , n
                   , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE
                   , MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE
                   , fd
                   , 0 );     
// ...
// writing to p; the changes exist only in memory
// ...

    // mapping now with MAP_SHARED
    void* p2= mmap ( NULL
                   , n
                   , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE
                   , MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE
                   , fd
                   , 0 );     
    memcpy(p2,p,n);  // copying everything from p to p2
    msync(p2,n);

    // unmap/remap p so it's ready for new changes
    munmap(p,n);
          p = mmap ( NULL
                   , n
                   , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE
                   , MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_NORESERVE
                   , fd
                   , 0 );     

This works, but:

the whole content is copied, not only the modified content
is this code legal? Is there any potential conflict between the 2 mapping, with an undefined behavior?


Rather than create a second mapping, you could simply do write(fd, p, n);.

@NateEldredge Indeed... Should I call fsync(fd) after that to ensure that all the changes are captured by the remapping of p, or is it unnecessary? In the code above I'm not even sure that the call to msync is necessary, but just in case...

write() is immediately visible to all other processes.  You only need fsync() if you want to ensure it is flushed back to disk, so as to be resilient to a system crash.

However, it is "unspecified" whether those (or any other) changes become visible in a private mapping such as p, and AFAIK neither msync() nor fsync() will help with that.  To be safe, you'll have to mmap it again.

@NateEldredge This is what I'm doing: after the file is updated I am unmapping/remapping p

Right. I'm just pointing out that you can't dispense with it.

Why MAP_PRIVATE? If you know you will make changes and will always commit them, just use MAP_SHARED--problem solved. (i.e. If you're just worried about efficient cache, no worries). If you make changes, but whether they are committed back to the original file is conditional (maybe yes, maybe no), then I'd copy the data to a temp file, map with MAP_SHARED and then copy back to the original file (if desired). Or, you can do MAP_PRIVATE, make changes, open a [separate] MAP_SHARED and copy to there. But, this may have aliasing issues.

@CraigEstey It's mainly the "maybe yes/maybe no". Creating a temporary file will do, but it means that the entire content has to be read/rewritten, which is not desirable if the file is very large and if only a small portion of it is potentially modified.

You can try my last option: open private, make changes, if commit: open shared and copy. But, see man mmap re. MAP_PRIVATE: It is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the mmap() call  are visible in the mapped region. So, it may suffer from the same issue re. memcpy with overlapping addresses(?). So, I'd write a diagnostic/unit test to verify that things will work. Of course, if you can keep track of the range of modifications, you'll only need to copy that part. Is that feasible for you?

@CraigEstey As suggested by @Nate I've replaced the shared mapping + memcpy with a write(), which is overall simpler, but the underlying idea is the same. After that I have to unmap/remap the private mapping. Keeping track of the modifications and write only them is a good idea (although a bit cumbersome...)

If that works okay, then all is well ... If you wish to be extra cautious, you could do the write to a temp file and rename it back. Then, there are no aliasing issues. So, if the file is myfile, then open myfile.TMP, write to that, close it, close the original file (rename(myfile.TMP,myfile)). Then, reopen and remap the file.

You may "log" the changes in array of struct iovec and use scattered write back to the file (writev), this will ensure some "transactional" semantic.
